# How to increase dhtmlxgantt chart date of year

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlxgantt tool to my project management tool. in My tool I have only 2013 year. I need increase it up to 2020. how can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use end_date config to set max value of the scale. Please, see more info in the next article:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__configuring_time_scale.html#settingtheminmaxvaluesofthescale